# I need a multi-column control that only displays one column in c#

Tags: c#

In my project I need a control that allows me to enter 2 columns.
First column is an Id Number
Second column is some Text.

**Example...**
row 1   Id = 1   Text = Day Shift
row 2   Id = 2   Text = Night Shift
But I only want to display the Text Values and then have the user select either Day Shift or Night Shift.

The program can then just lookup the corresponding value (1 or 2) for whatever text they chose.
 - In Microsoft Access I would just have used a ComboBox and hidden the first column.

I cannot find anything in Visual Studio 2017 to put on my Windows Form that easily does this.

I want to set it all up at design time and the closest I have come so far is by using a LISTVIEW control using a display type of LIST (I don't want column headers either.

It seems to do what I want except that it always wants me to leave a blank space below my lines of text - presumably for a horizontal scrollbar even though I set it to False in the properties and it does not actually display a scroll bar.

If I resize the ListView control to just be big enough for my two rows of text it tries to display the 2nd row next to the 1st row and still leaves a blank space below the rows.

See the below images, assuming I uploaded them properly, I am totally new to asking questions here.

Is there a way I can achieve this - should I be using a different control?

The closest I came to what I need is the top image

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

Thanks and I hope it all makes sense.

In reply to Harry I added the below...

After adding the ListView control to my form  I then clicked on the little arrow selector (in the top right of the ListView control).to bring up the collections list popup box.

It is there I set the view to be ‘List’ so I don’t have to have column header, then I clicked on EDIT ITEMS to get another pop-up screen…Click the [Add] button to add items in the rows.

Then I changed the Text to ‘Day Shift’ for the first member (and ‘Night Shift’ for the second member).

To add values in the rows for the 2nd column I then clicked the  SUBITEMS (collection) box in properties to get the next popup…

I then clicked the Add button and created a new Text item (value 1)
and repeated this for the Night Shift member but gave it a value of 2.
These values are to be the actual ID values (in the 2nd column).

Note…
I did create column Headers but setting the View to List means I don’t get them displayed (and don’t want them displayed).
but I did notice that changing the View to List also removes the second column (Id) from the ListView display.
As I don’t need the Id values (1 & 2) displayed I am not going to worry about what happened to them disappearing in the display. All I did, though, was just changed the View from Details to List.

Sorry If I’m misunderstanding you but at this point there is no actual code I am creating, no doubt Visual Studio 2017 does that itself but I am not looking at that. Is that what you needed to see?

Hope this makes better sense though, I did try and include images but the system will not let me do that until my reputation points are higher, sorry.

Thanks

Comment: Hi, thanks for the effort, can you also paste your code

Comment: There is no code as such as I want to do this all at Design Time & not in code.
If I need to code it instead then I may just put up with having the blank space below the 'Night Shift' text.
I am just learning this for now and am expanding on what I need to do by comparing things to how I would have done it via Microsoft Access (never good to compare really but it's how I like to learn). Thx.

Comment: I think you are misunderstanding, you have an Array bound to the ListView - how you are doing the binding is the question? are you looping it may be your loop needs to be fixed.

Comment: I have added more to the question - above, in reply to Harry. I added up there as it was a lot of text and I tried to include images but was not allowed, sorry.